# Set custom post type permalink to root in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, permalinks

I created a custom post type to organize a certain type of pages, but since my WordPress permalinks settings are set to `/blog/%postname%/` this new custom post type permalink is `/blog/new-post-type`. I do not want to remove `/blog/` from the site's permalink settings because we do use that for blog posts. How do I remove `/blog/` from the new post type so it acts like the default pages permalinks in WordPress which is `www.website.com/name-of-page/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rewrite` parameter of [the `register_post_type()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite) has a parameter of `with_front` that when set to `false` will not prepend URLs with the front base specified by the permalink structure.

```php
register_post_type( 'cpt', array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
    )
);
```

The above will prevent `/blog/` from being on URLs for your CPT's posts, however, I do not know if that means the CPT's URLs will work at root.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why everything I searched I could not find it or remember the "with_front". Thanks so much!